# How does the if statement know to continue adding from day 7 amount for the solution?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, if-statement

1. I am seeking to understand why my code doesn't work, please explain the logic behind my algorithm being flawed.
2. why on the solution code the nested-if statement knows to continue adding from the loss on day 7 on without specifing to add the investment amount.

> You put 1000 dollars into a new cryptocurrency. Good luck!
> Over ten years, the value of the investment increases by 5% each year.
> In the seventh year, the investment loses 75% instead of increasing. Eeek!
> Use a for loop to log how many years it has been and how much the investment is worth for each year.
> let investment = 1000;

/// MY SOLUTION  ///

```
const interest = .05;  
let balance = investment + (investment * interest);

for (i = 1; i < 11; i++){  
  if (i === 7){  
  balance = balance * -.75;  
  } else if (i < 7 || i > 7) {  
    balance = balance * i;  
  }    
  console.log("Year " + i + " investment amount $" + balance);  
}
```

/// SOLUTION ///

```
for (i = 1; i < 11; i++){  
   if (i === 7){  
       investment = investment * .25;  
   } else {  
      investment = investment * 1.05;  
   }   
    console.log("It has been " + i + " years and we have $" + investment + " left");  
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code:

- You forgot to include the given instruction which is `let investment = 1000;`
- In this line `let balance = investment + (investment * interest);`, your balance is already calculated for the first year and you're calculating another 10 years within your loop. You can either change (don't choose both):

  1. `let balance = investment + (investment * interest);` => `let balance = 1000;`
  2. `for (i = 1; i < 11; i++)` => `for (i = 2; i < 11; i++)`
- When `i === 7` (7th year), you are multiplying the negative value to your balance. What should do instead is minus 75% from your balance. In code, you can write:

  ```js
  balance = balance - (balance * 0.75)
  ```

  (or)

  ```js
  balance -= balance * -.75;
  ```

  In the solution, they wrote `investment = investment * 0.25` which means exactly the same thing, because you lose 75% of your balance, so the remaining should be 25% (100% - 75%) of your balance.
- Your `else-if` statement is not wrong, but I would suggest writing only `else` since `(i < 7 || i > 7)` === `i !== 7`
- The last mistake you made is with this line `balance = balance * i;`, instead of multiplying your balance with the `interest`, you multiply it with `i` which is an iterator going from 1 to 11. You should change it from `balance = balance * i;` to `balance = balance * interest;`

> If you still have any doubt regarding my explanation, feel free to let me know. I'll try my best to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I see a couple of things in the code you shared

1. `investement` is not declared in the code you shared
2. The problem mentions a 5% fixed rate and you are using `i` as rate (which is the month that goes from 1 to 10)
3. Asking for `else if (i < 7 || i > 7)` is the same as asking for `(i != 7)` which is the same as the `else` for the `if(i ===7)`
4. Also I notice that you apply interests from the first moment(first day) when you write thie `let balance = investment + (investment * interest);` and that is not how interest is calculated unless specified otherwise
5. Losing 75% is writen like this `balance = balance - (balance * 0.75);`  which is the same as `balance = balance* 0.25`